# Unity c# Iterate over a Firebase Snapshot

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have this json database

```
{ 
"shops" : {
        "7" : {
          "cod1" : {
            "name" : "name3",
            "description" : "xxx",

          },
          "cod2" : {
            "name" : "name2",
            "description" : "xxx",

          },
          "cod3" : {
            "name" : "name1",
            "description" : "xxx",

          },
```

I need to iterate over the snapshot to get cod1,cod2,cod3 and i need to do something for every one of those codes that I do not previously know

```
public void load(string city){
//city is number 7 in this case;
        Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser user = auth.CurrentUser;
        FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
                        .RootReference.Child ("shops").Child (city)
            .GetValueAsync ().ContinueWith (task => {
            if (task.IsFaulted) {
                // Handle the error...
            } else if (task.IsCompleted) {
                DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                int i = 0;

                foreach (DataSnapshot shop in snapshot.Children) {
                        debug.text = "\nstarting with #" + i.ToString () + ": " + shop.Key+";\n";

                        i++;
                }

            }
        });
```

I need debug.text to show "Starting with #1: cod1" and then again with cod2 and cod3

Now I get something like "Starting with #1: 7" that is the key of the parent of those codes

Is there a way to get those codes?

Answer (score -1):

Well, first of all, your JSON isn't really formatted as it should be. If you want data to be returned accurately, "shops" should be an array, not an object. Like so:

```
"shops" : [
  "cod1" : {
        "name" : "name3",
        "description" : "xxx"
      },
      "cod2" : {
        "name" : "name2",
        "description" : "xxx"
      },
      "cod3" : {
        "name" : "name1",
        "description" : "xxx"
      }
]
```

Currently, "shops" is an object, which has a child object "7", which is the parent of cod1, cod2, and cod3. Which is also why you're seeing "7".